# Filtering on DateTimeField with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model with a DateTimeField:

```
class MyShell(models):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=true)
```

I have an api linked to it using Django Rest Framework:

```
class ShellMessageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(name="created",lookup_type="gte")

    class Meta:
        model = ShellMessage
        fields = ['created']


class ShellListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
        List all ShellMessages
    """
    serializer_class = ShellMessageSerializer
    queryset = ShellMessage.objects.all()
    filter_class = ShellMessageFilter
```

When I hit my API using the following URL it works perfectly:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shell/?created=2014-07-17
# It returns all shell with a date greater than the one provided in URL
```

But, I want to do more than that by filtering base on a date and a time. I tried the following URL without success:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shell/?created=2014-07-17T10:36:34.960Z
# It returns an empty array whereas there are items with a created field greater than 2014-07-17T10:36:34.960Z
```

If you guys know how to proceed... I don't find any good informations or example in django-filters documentation...

Comment: Could you try this url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shell/?created=2014-07-17%2010:36:34.960 ?

Comment: I think I'm in this case : https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1338

Comment: The first person also suggests removing the T from the URL, so maybe this will work for your too.

Answer (score 4):

Simpler solution if you don't care about fractions of seconds: replace the "T" with space (%20):

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/shell/?created=2014-07-17%2010:36:34
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you want, but you could simply convert from Unix time. E.g.:

```
def filter_unix_dt(queryset, value):
    if not value:
        return queryset

    try:
        unix_time = int(value)
        t = datetime.fromtimestamp(unix_time)
        result = queryset.filter(created__gte=t)
        return result
    except ValueError:
        return queryset


class ShellMessageFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(action=filter_unix_dt)

    class Meta:
        model = ShellMessage
        fields = ['created']
```

Comment: Awesome reply, but the django_filter should be CharField instead of DateTimeFilter: "created = django_filters.CharField(action=filter_unix_dt)"

Answer (score 1):

The issue and solution are documented in this DRF issue page: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1338

TL;DR: A Django ISO conversion 'issue' is preventing DRF from working as you are expecting. A fix for this has been written in DRF, allowing you to use `IsoDateTimeField` instead of `DateTimeField`. Just replaying the `T` with a space in your request param value also works.